# turf js booleanPointOnLine always return false

Tags: jquery, turfjs

I'm trying to check if the coordinates clicked by the user is with in the lineString or not.
I tried the `boolean-point-on-line` in turf js to check but it always return `false` except if the point coordinates are exactly the same in the lineString coordinates

Here is the sample code

```
var line = {
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
    "type": "LineString",
    "coordinates": [
        [
            125.95258164431453,
            8.685291544847786
        ],
        [
            125.95232752816695,
            8.685149645776638
        ],
        [
            125.9519648088196,
            8.68522476398713
        ],
        [
            125.9516401148043,
            8.685516506081687
        ],
        [
            125.951592738644,
            8.685694826544953
        ]
    ]
}
}

var pt = {
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
        125.95233365893367,
        8.685152837740315
    ]
}
}

turf.booleanPointOnLine(pt, line)
```

This is the result of the coordinates

[image]